# Kendo Grid with Angular - Default Sort Order

Tags: kendo-grid, angular-kendo

How to get Kendo Grid to sort by a specific field if using k-data-source?

Here is my HTML:

Here is my Controller:

```
getBusinessUnits();
function getBusinessUnits() {
    operatorService.getBusinessUnits()
    .success(function (data) {

        $scope.businessUnits = data;
    });
};

$scope.gridOptions = {
    batch: false,
    reorderable: true,
    sortable: true,
    editable: "inline",



columns: [
  { template: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up" style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="MoveUp(#=OperatorBusinessUnitID#)"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" style="cursor:pointer"></i>', title: "List Order" },
  { field: "OperatorBusinessUnitID", title: "Business Unit ID" },
  { field: "vchDescription", title: "Business Unit Name" },
  { field: "vchOperatorSystemID", title: "Operator System ID"},
  {
      command: [
        { name: "edit", text: " " },
        { name: "destroy", text: " " },
      ], title: "Action"
  }
]
```

};

The data returned by the service from the SQL database is returned by the SQL stored procedure in the order that I need it.  However, the grid automatically defaults to sorting it my the ID column.  Is there any way to tell it which field to sort by default if I am not "creating" a datasource object in my Angular Controller?